# "export 'ICON_PATHS' was not found in 'ionicons/icons'

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, vue.js, ionic

Nunca he instalado ionicons porque no necesito los icons, este error me empezo a salir hace poco tiempo con ionic/vue y deja de aparecer cuando remuevo el

```
 import Ionic from '@ionic/vue'
 import IonicVue from '@ionic/vue'
```

Con cualquiera de las dos lineas de arriba me sale error con ICON_PATHS y al removerlas el error desaparece pero me salta error por los componentes de ionic ya que ese import es la forma de decir que usare ionic/vue. Alguien que haya resuelto ese error?

He probado:

- Instalar y desinstalar el paquete de ionicons.
- Eliminar carpeta node modules y package-lock.json volviendo a instalar npn.
- Definiendo el path de ionicons que supongo se instala por defecto con ionic/vue.

Las soluciones simples ya las he probado, necesito algo mas serio, alguien que pueda ayudarme. PD: Cambien probé con yarn ya que algunos decían que el problema era por npm lo cual no tiene sentido pero igual lo probé y nada.

Comment: `npm install ionicons@4.5.9-1 --save-dev` Esto funcionó para mi.

Comment: Pues quita el error y permite mostrar la app pero me dejo la pantalla en blanco

Answer (score 0):

Yo instalé la version 4.5.0 de ionicons y ya no tengo ese problema. Pero si no usas los iconos hay otra manera de solucionarlo, en la carpeta de tu proyecto edita el archivo node_modules/@ionic/vue/dist/ionic-vue.esm.js y busca ICON_PATHS, son dos lineas y comenta las dos. Eso arregla el problema de que no se encuentra ICON_PATHS

[image: Editar ionic-vue.esm.js]

Answer (score 0):

Usa este comando:

```
npm install ionicons@4.5.9-1
```

e inicia/reinicia tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Yo nunca e instalado ionicons sin embargo en mis proyectos tengo el de Material Design Icons esta muy bueno y tiene muchisimos iconos.

para instalarlo este es el codigo

```
npm install @mdi/font
```

puedes echarles un ojo a los iconos para que los veas.

https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/7.2.96/